# How to bring back Wallet's prompting?

Tags: google-wallet

I used to use Google Pay to store my boarding passes and it had a fantastic feature: prompting me to open the boarding pass when I was close to the flight, or the airport (not sure which but it worked great).

I was moved to Wallet which is still fine, except that it stopped prompting me.

Is there a way to bring back this killer feature, or has it been abandoned?

I am in France if that matters.